# Error upgrading to 5.65

Tags: upgrade, drupal-7

I'm using Drupal 7.98, upgrading CiviCRM to 5.65. PHP 7.4.
Im getting this fatal error

TypeError: Return value of Civi\ActionSchedule\MappingBase::getLabel() must be of the type string

IS anyone else getting this? Upgrade to 5.64 works fine.

Answer (score 3):

Apply this patch https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/27354 until a fixed release is out.